# SQL Query GROUP BY Issue in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, lumen, laravel-query-builder

I wrote the following MySQL query to get inbox messages of a user with each user and also with last message...

```
select *, `chat_channel` as `channel`, MAX(id) as max_id from `messages` 
where (`message_to` = 2 or `message_from` = 2) 
and (`delete_one` <> 2 and `delete_two` <> 2) 
group by `channel` 
order by `max_id` desc limit 40 offset 0
```

Laravel Method which I use...

```
public static function getInboxMessages($user_id, $limit = 40, $offset = 0, $search_key = null)
{
    return Message::hasSearch($search_key)->select("*", DB::raw("MAX(id) as max_id"))->where(function ($sql) use (
        $user_id
    ) {
        $sql->where('message_to', '=', $user_id);
        $sql->orWhere('message_from', '=', $user_id);
    })->where(function ($sql) use ($user_id) {
        $sql->where('delete_one', '<>', $user_id);
        $sql->where('delete_two', '<>', $user_id);
    })->with([
        'sender' => function ($q) {
            $q->select('id', 'uid', 'username', 'full_name', 'picture');
        }
    ])->with([
        'receiver' => function ($q) {
            $q->select('id', 'uid', 'username', 'full_name', 'picture');
        }
    ])->orderBy('max_id', 'DESC')->groupBy('chat_channel')->offset($offset)->limit($limit)->get();
}
```

However, when I run this query in phpMyAdmin I encounter the following error...

> 1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.messages.id' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

When I run Laravel code directly then I don't receive any error but I do get the records ordered by as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `phpMyAdmin -> YourDB -> SQL Tab`

Use following command :

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';`

this will enable only full group by for your sql.

To revert the above command changes use :

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`

Answer (score 0):

it's the `STRICT MODE` of mysql for aggregation.
take notice that when you group by something and you select another non aggregated field, the value of that field is not correct 100%. aggregated field are those like  the fields you are grouping by, `count(field)`, `sum(field)`,...etc

if you are willing to take that risk, go to `config\database.php` and edit the `strict => true` to `false`

```
'prefix' => '',
'strict' => false,
'engine' => null,
```

it is not recommended, and you should rework your query with a `join` on a `group by` `select`

```
select x from table right join (select gb from table group by gb) as grouped on grouped.gb = table.gb
```

something like this